# Solve Lyapunov equation for $Q$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, control-theory, sylvester-equation

Given Lyapunov equation: $AP+PA^T+Q=0$ and the linear system $\dot{x}=Ax$ is globally asymptotically stable i.e. the real part of all eignvalues of $A$ is strictly negative . The theorem says that choosing $Q>0 \implies P>0 $ and is unique . However , Does choosing $P>0$ guarantee that $Q>0$ ?

Edit: Is there a sufficient condition less strict than $A$ being symmetric such as
$A^T+A<0$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,  $Q$ may be indefinite. Consider

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ -1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}, \quad P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

But what you guarantee is that $Q \not <0$, since otherwise you would prove instability.

Comment: Is there a sufficient condition that would guarantee $Q>0$? , for example the symmetric part of $A$ being positive definite i.e. $A+A^T >0$ .

Comment: @abc1455 If the symmetric part of $A$ was positive definite then the system would be unstable. This is because of the inequality $\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{\rm min}(A+A^T)\leq \operatorname{Re} \lambda(A)$.

Comment: sorry for the mistake , I meant negative definite .